# React Ace Editor value not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor

I'm looking to display some code through the value props in my react component but the editor just stays blank and does not show any values. I can type within the editor and everything seems to be working, including syntax highlighting. No errors in sight. Am I missing something obvious?

I should note, I'm using next.js and react-ace as shown here:
https://github.com/mingderwang/ace-editor-with-next

Here is my main index.js page code:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const CodeEditor = dynamic(import("../components/codeEditor"), { ssr: false });

export default () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CodeEditor value={"for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {\n  console.log(i)\n}"} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here is the Ace CodeEditor component code:

```
import ReactAce from "react-ace-editor";
import React from "react";

function CodeEditor(props) {
  return (
    <ReactAce
      value={props.value}
      mode="javascript"
      theme="xcode"
      setReadOnly={false}
      style={{
        height: "500px",
        fontSize: "16px",
      }}
    />
  );
}
export default CodeEditor;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library **react-ace-editor** has implemented the properties as follows:

```js
CodeEditor.propTypes = {
  editorId: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  setReadOnly: PropTypes.bool,
  setValue: PropTypes.string,
  theme: PropTypes.string,
  mode: PropTypes.string,
  style: PropTypes.object,
};
```

Prop called **setValue** is the one which passes on the code string to the editor. Try renaming value to setValue.

Comment: That worked perfect. Value is displaying properly now!